# C++ - Finding x Factor of a math expression

Tags: c++

I'm trying to get the x factor of an input math expression, but it seems buggy.
Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>

using namespace std;


int main(){
    char a[100]; 
    int res = 0; // final answer
    int temp = 0; // factor of the x we are focused on - temporarily
    int pn = 0; // power of 10 - used for converting digits to number
    int conv; // used for conversion of characters to int

    cout<< "Enter a: ";
    cin>> a; //input expression

    for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
        // checking if the character is x - then get the factor
        if(a[i]=='x'){
            for(int j=1; j<=i+1; j++){
                conv = a[i-j] - '0'; // conversion
                if(conv>=0 && conv<=9){ // check if the character is a number
                    temp = temp + conv*pow(10, pn); // temporary factor - using power of 10 to convert digit to number
                    pn++; // increasing the power
                }
                else{
                    if(a[i-j]=='-'){
                        temp = -temp; // check if the sign is - or +
                    }
                    break;
                }
                if(i-j==0){
                    break;
                }
            }
            res = res+temp; // adding the x factor to other ones
            pn = 0;
            temp = 0;
        }
    }
    cout<< res;
    return 0;
}
```

It doesn't work for some inputs, for example:
100x+3x gives 102 and 3x+3997x-4000x gives -1

But works for 130x and 150x!

Is there a problem with my code, or is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: `pow` takes and returns floating point values, which are not always precisely what you'd expect for an integer exponentiation (and when there is an error, it's often slightly below the expected value, so casting to `int` means a off-by-one error below the expected value); I strongly suspect the coercion back to `int` is biting you for some inputs. You'll need to roll your own integer based `pow` (or find a better way to do this in general).

Comment: You might also want to consider using [`std::strtol()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/) that already takes care of the parsing.

Comment: You should use `#include <cmath>` instead of `#include<math.h>` for C++.  Also like @ShadowRanger pointed out you have a rounding error since `std::pow()` takes a double as the base.  Consider using something like `int y = (int)round(x);` Also try using functions instead of dumping all your code in `main`.

Comment: Thanks a LOT ShadowRanger! Rolled a power function and it works!

Comment: that's exactly right.  I'm constantly amazed that they didn't implement that

Answer (score 0):

I think you're not parsing the +.  There may be some other problem I can't see in the original code, probably not.  Here's the X-File:

```
int main(){
    char a[100];
    int res(0);

    cout << "Enter a: ";
    cin >> a;

    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        if(a[i] == 'x'){
            int temp(0);
            int pn(0);

            for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++){
                int conv = a[i - j] - '0';

                if(conv >= 0 && conv <= 9){
                    temp += conv*pow(10, pn);
                    pn++;
                } else if(a[i - j] == '-') {
                    temp = -temp;
                    break;
                } else if(a[i - j] == '+') {
                    break;
                } else {
                    // what to do...
                }
            }

            res += temp;
        }
    }

    cout << res;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Actually, he assumes any character which isn't a digit separate two terms of his sum (for instance "3x3997x" is interpreted as "3x+3997x", "3potato3997x" is interpreted as "3+3997x"). Your program treats things slightly differently, for instance, you'll interpret "3x3997x" as "3x+33997x". I guess neither is really incorrect since one could argue those are ill formed inputs (well, set aside the possible rounding errors when coercing floats to ints as shadowranger pointed out).

Comment: I am certain you are right.  What is an x factor hehe?